# What caused my TNT Minecarts to explode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So I'm planning a violent execution:

[image: HE KNOWS WHAT HE DID]

I'm planning to set up a load of TNT carts around the convicted, and ignite them all at once by activating the rails.

[image]

So far so good...

[image]

The carts have started jostling, but no problem, I can fit more on.

[image: WAT]

Wat? I was just blasted a few chunks away as all the carts exploded at once. The rails weren't powered.

The wiki only has the following to say:

> When given a redstone signal, they turn on and will activate any cart that goes over them. When off, they act as normal rails.

and on the carts themselves:

> It will detonate on these conditions:
>
> - It moves over a powered Activator Rail (after 4 second delay like the TNT block).
> - It derails and falls more than three blocks.
> - It's destroyed while in motion.
> - It's destroyed by fire, lava or an explosion.
> - It turns on a curved track with a solid block or entity located beside the track (in the previous movement direction).

What then caused my carts to explode?

Comment: Look at that face! You **monster**!

Comment: I'm guessing the `curved track with a solid block or entity located beside the track` is to blame.  I will test it.

Comment: @Coronus **HE KNOWS WHAT HE DID**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It would appear that if 2 TNT minecarts run into each other **on a curve with sufficient speed**, it will set them off.

Step 1: Build a loop.
[image: Step 1]

Step 2: See if Minecarts explode when place next to each other.
[image: Step 2]

Nope, looks like this is safe.

Step 3: See if Minecarts explode when across from each other.
[image: Step 3]

Nope, this seems fine too.

Step 4: Try to make minecarts explode on straight sections.
[image: Step 4]

This never set it off (this picture is different because I tried many times to figure out where it was exploding).

Step 5: Make minecarts crash on a curve.
[image: Step 5]

Ah ha! This resulted in an explosion.
[image: Boom Boom]

This did not happen every time the minecarts collided in the corner, so this seems to be somewhat randomly caused.

**Further Science**

Does it need to be 2 TNT carts?
[image: Extra 1]

No! In fact, regular Minecarts seemed to set off the TNT more frequently.
[image: KaBOOM]

Also, chickens are friends, not <del>food</del> fireworks.
[image: I like chickens Eddie!]

Comment: Damn it, I had written that before and decided that it was incorrect.

Comment: @batophobia dat fov

Comment: @Retrosaur Trippy! FOV hurts my brain.

Comment: Ok, now explain why I get the same results with a single length of track with no corners!

Comment: @Retrosaur What can I say, I like to see **EVERYTHING**

Comment: @fredley **IT WAS HIM**

Comment: +1 for "Also, chickens are friends, not fireworks."